# SQL (or linq to sql) works slower when called from winforms than when called on web application?

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

We ran into strange sql / linq behaviour today:

We used to use a web application to perform some intensive database actions on our system. Recently we moved to a winforms interface for various reasons.

We found out that performance has seriously decreased: an action that used to take about 15 minutes now takes as long as one whole hour.  The strange thing is that **It's the exact same method being called.** The method performs quite a bit of read / write using linq2sql, and profiling on the client machine showed that the problematic section is on the SQL action itself, in the linq's "Save" method.

The only difference between the cases is that on one case the method is called from a web application's code behind (MVC in this case), and on the other from a windows form.

The one idea I could come up with is that SQL performance has something to do with the identity of the user accessing the db, but I could not find any support for that assumption.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very old issue but I happened to run into the question just now. So for whom is may concern nowadays, the solution (and there-before the problem) was frustratingly silly. Linq2SQL was configured on the dev machines to **constantly write a log to console**.

This was causing a huge delay due to the simple act of outputing large amount of text to the console. On the web server the log was not being written, and therefore - no performance drawback. There was a colossal face-palming once we figured this one out. Thanks for the helpers, I hope this answer will help someone solve it faster next time.

Unattended logging. That was the problem.

Comment: You should mark your own answer as correct so the question no longer appears as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run both tests from the same machine?  If not hardware differences could be the issue... or network... one could be in a higher speed section of your network... like in the same vlan as the sql server.  Try running the client code on the same server the web app was running on.

Also if your app is updating progress in a sycronous manner the app could be waiting a long time for display to update... as apposed to working with a stream ala response.write.

If you are actually outputting progress as you go you should make sure that the progress updates are events and that the display of those happens on another thread so that the processing isn't waiting on display.  Actually you probably should put the processing on its own thread... and just have an event handler take care of the updates... that is a whole different discussion.  The point is that your app could be waiting to update the display of progress.

Comment: Thanks Jsobo. It was tested on the same machine, so hardware differences are not the issue. Also, the progress updates are done between the calls to save and not during the sql action, while the delay is caused by the sql itlself, according to the profiling. However I will try separating the processing to another thread, and will update here.

Comment: Okay. A separate thread did not do the magic. Any more ideas?

Comment: try profiling the webapp to see if the result are the same function call by function call... eventually you will find your extra time... Also just drop the status updates and see how much time your get back.. There has to be something different in the code... and I doubt it is the actual sql calls being that different between the two apps.

Comment: Did you ever find the problem?

Comment: jsobo: yes. posted the answer. I really hope it's long ago irrelevant for you.